# relative power dB?

Tags: python, math, signal-processing

I use a dongle USB RTL 2832 for capture samples. I want to plot a PSD (power density spectral) with this library : [Pyrtlsdr](https://github.com/roger-/pyrtlsdr).

With this code it's possible:

```
from pylab import *
from rtlsdr import *

sdr = RtlSdr()

# configure device
sdr.sample_rate = 2.4e6
sdr.center_freq = 95e6
sdr.gain = 4

samples = sdr.read_samples(256*1024)

# use matplotlib to estimate and plot the PSD
psd(samples, NFFT=1024, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6, Fc=sdr.center_freq/1e6)
xlabel('Frequency (MHz)')
ylabel('Relative power (dB)')

show()
```

I don't understand `"ylabel"`, what is relative power (dB)? If we said `dbm`, we compare the power with 1 mW ? but in this example I don't understand.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Part of the problem is that you don't know what the voltage you're measuring means.  Several factors could be at play: the front-end may have automatic gain control (AGC), filters and amplifiers may be present, etc.  The best you can say without knowing the details is that it's a relative power measurement, but you don't know to what.  If you need to understand that for your system, then you'll need to analyze the front-end and see what all the gains and losses are, and then see how that translates to samples taken.  Keep in mind things like AGC can make determining this difficult.

Comment: oh ok so if someone tell me, dB compared to....? I can juste ask, it's relative power ?

Comment: PSD is usually defined in W/Hz, but when sampling, it makes things more abstract.  You could say that the result is (V^2)/Hz.  The problem is what does the voltage mean?  Watts?  Milliwatts?  Something else (most likely)?  The only thing you can say for sure is that it's relative, you just don't know to what exactly, unless you really analyze the system.  This stuff isn't really my forté, but I hope that helps.

Comment: ok thanks ! it help me to understand so thanks again !